# The constructor Teacher(Teacher) is undefined

Tags: java, inheritance, composition

I am using a copy constructor and Inheritance in a class called 'Department' to call the information from class 'Teacher' which is a sub-class of 'Person'. After creating my set/get methods, I get the above error. Anyone have any insight as to why this is occurring?

### Code from 'Department' class:

```
public class Department {
private String deptName;
private int numMajors;
private Teacher[] listTeachers; //inherits from Person class
private Student[] listStudents; //inherits from Person class

    // First constructor for Department
    public Department(String dn, int nm, Teacher[] listTeachers, Student[] listStudents) {
    this.deptName = dn;
    this.numMajors = nm;

    this.listTeachers = new Teacher[listTeachers.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.listTeachers.length; i++)
    {
        this.listTeachers[i] = new Teacher (listTeachers[i]);
    }

    //set method for Teachers Array
    public void setListTeachers (Teacher[] other) {
    this.listTeachers = new Teacher[other.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < listTeachers.length; i++) {
        this.listTeachers[i] = new Teacher (other[i]);
    }
}

    //get method for Teachers Array
    public Teacher[] getListTeachers() {
    Teacher[] copyTeachers = new Teacher[listTeachers.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < copyTeachers.length; i++) {
        copyTeachers[i] = new Teacher(this.listTeachers[i]);
    }
    return copyTeachers;
}
```

Here are the lines giving me errors:

1)    `this.listTeachers[i] = new Teacher (listTeachers[i]);`

2) `this.listTeachers[i] = new Teacher (other[i]);`

3) `copyTeachers[i] = new Teacher(this.listTeachers[i]);`

### Code from 'Teacher' class:

```
public class Teacher extends Person {
private String id;
private int salary;
private int num_yr_prof;

//Constructor for use in Teacher main method.
public Teacher(String n, int a, String s, boolean al, String i, int sal, int numyr) {
    super(n, a, s, al);
    this.id = i;
    this.salary = sal;
    this.num_yr_prof = numyr;
}

//Copy constructor for use in Department class.
public Teacher (String n, int a, String s, boolean al, Teacher other) {
    super(n, a, s, al);
    if (other == null) {
        System.out.println("Fatal Error!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    this.id = other.id;
    this.salary = other.salary;
    this.num_yr_prof = other.num_yr_prof;
}
```

Comment: You didn't write a copy-constructor. A copy-constructor would be `public Teacher(Teacher other) {`

Comment: Unlike C++, Java does not automatically create an implicit copy constructor for you. If you want to call it, it needs an explicit definition.

Comment: @AndyThomas so ---> 

public Teacher (String n, int a, String s, boolean al, Teacher other)

is not an explicit constructor?

Comment: @Isiah D Yes, that is an explicit constructor, but it is not a copy constructor. A copy constructor takes a single input parameter as stated in other comments above. the constructor you cite has five input parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your copy constructor might look like this:

```
    public Teacher(Teacher teacher) {
        this( teacher.n, teacher.a, teacher.s, teacher.al, 
              teacher.id, teacher.salary, teacher.num_yr_prof );
    }
```

Since you do not show the code for the Person class, I have used the variable names n, a, s, and al here. They should be replaced by whatever those variables are named in the Person class. This, of course, assumes that those variables are either public or protected. If they are private, you need to use the getters for those variables (preferred even if they are public or protected).

Comment: I took your advice and added a slightly different version of this in my code and it worked. Thank you. I understand why I was getting the errors. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Andy Thomas. You are, of course, correct. Possibly best to use only the else-clause line, and let an exception be thrown if the argument is null.

Answer (score 1):

You need to to your Teacher class a constructor that accepts a Teacher:

```
public Teacher(Teacher teacher) {
// do something
}
```